# TextArea field in jsp

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

Experts,

One small question.I have a JSP form page which has Text Area field.
I have a string contains 300 lines. When I paste the content in text area field, it accepting the content. but when i submit the form, page got stuck there only and not moving to servlet.

If i give less than 50/60 lines. its accepting and moving the content to servlet. Any pointers would help how to achieve getting this 300 lines of content to servlet from jsp.

Thanks

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the essential part of your code? You give very little information for anyone to help you with.

Comment: i couldnt edit this as its keep showing some error  even after modifying it. I have illustrated the code and explained in this link what i have tried. can you please check and assist. https://codeshare.io/5Ovr9P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use method type post

```html
<form action="TEST" method="post">
    <textarea rows="11" cols="160" name="tt" ></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="okkk">
</form>
```